# How to turn off Nagle in .NET 4.5 ClientWebSocket?

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, nagle

I would like use .NET 4.5 ClientWebSocket (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but Wireshark reveals, that Nagle's algorithm is turned on, which is a pain in the neck. Can anybody tell me how to reach ClientWebSocket's Socket.NoDelay property?
Even a hack would be appreciated...

Comment: You can take a look at the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebSockets/ClientWebSocket.cs) but I'm not sure how much luck you will have.

Comment: I have tried it, with no luck... I couldn't figure out, where the socket is hidden. Maybe anyone has spotted it?

Comment: @xy Any luck in your experiments? Last resort brute force solution might be turning of Nagle in windows registry.